# Inserting code via include() echoes content

Tags: php

I'm a little bit confused by the behaviour of the `include()` (and all related) functions.  If I have a file `library.php`, which contains some code (in my case, a single array):

```
<?php
$exampleArray = array(
    "Item1" => "Item 1 description",
    "Item2" => "Item 2 description"
);
?>
```

and I want to be able to access that array in another file (`index.php`), then in `index.php` I need to do `require_once('library.php');`.  If I don't have the PHP tags, then the code is echoed. However, [this comment on the PHP site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#103011) implies that, regardless of whether the tags are included or not, if the header of the included file is modified, the content will be echoed.

1. Is this right? If I change the file I want to include to `library.txt`, but still have the PHP tags, the content isn't echoed (although I realise the content type is still almost certainly `text/plain` in both cases)
2. The comment also says 'It only takes a single wrong character to show everyone in the world that information.' - what single wrong character is he referring to?

Comment: Keep in mind the comments in the php manual are often very very wrong. All I can think of is hes talking about stuff like `>?php` instead of `<?php`, and to that I would say "duh!". Programming syntax is strict.

Answer (score 2):

So why not just keep it with the `<?php` tags? So far with what I have tested, anything without the tags will not be parsed as PHP. IIRC, anything in the PHP tags get parsed by PHP, so you will need those tags for PHP to parse the things inside the included file.

```
<?php
require_once("test.txt");
echo $exampleArray["Item1"];
?>
```

with no `<?php` tags returns

```
$exampleArray = array( "Item1" => "Item 1 description", "Item2" => "Item 2 description" );
```

if I use `require_once("test.php");`, without `<?php` tags in the filet still gives me the unparsed content.

So you need the tags in order for it to work.

http://meowman.sytes.net/so/incfile/tag.php and http://meowman.sytes.net/so/incfile/test.php show what echos when the include file has tags.

http://meowman.sytes.net/so/incfile/notag.php and http://meowman.sytes.net/so/incfile/testno.php show what echos when the include file has no tags.

Answer (score 0):

Always - yes always - use the opening tags in a PHP file you want to include. (closing tags not necessarily needed though).

if you don't use the php opening tags, the content will also be visible to a user who simply requests the file via HTTP, hence the user can see the source code, because the code isn't actually parsed by the PHP interpreter but just being echo'd as plain text.